# Stop and start service in-order on a remote server

Tags: powershell, service

I want to write a script to check 4 service on a server if they have status running when we stop them by order and start them on the other hand with delay.

First service must check that it is running and then start with others therefore we use delay.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content “.\server.txt”
$servicename4 = "Orbit Utveckling Consul"
$servicename3 = "Orbit Utveckling Identity"
$servicename2 = "Orbit Utveckling Service"
$servicename1 = "Orbit Utveckling Integration"
$delay = 60 # Ange i sekunder.

foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    $getservicestatus1 = Get-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server
    if ($getservicestatus1 -eq "Running") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server -Status stopped
        Write-Host "$server $servicename1 Stoppat!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan $servicename2 stoppar..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }
    $getservicestatus2 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename2 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus2 -eq "Running") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename2 -ComputerName $server -Status stopped
        Write-Host "$server $servicename2 Stoppat!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server stoppar..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }
    $getservicestatus3 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename3 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus3 -eq "Running") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename3 -ComputerName $server -Status stopped
        Write-Host "$server $servicename3 Stoppat!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server stoppar..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }
    $getservicestatus4 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename4 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus4 -eq "Running") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename4 -ComputerName $server -Status stopped
        Write-Host "$server $servicename4 Stoppat!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server stoppar..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }
}

# Filen startar tjänsten Drift_Cosmic på varje IX3a i txt-filen.
# Det görs med en delay på ett antal sekunder mellan varje start.
# Detta är en testfil tills dess att en riktig testkörning
# har gjorts i Drift.
Write-Host "$servicename4, $servicename3, $servicename2, $servicename1 startas med $delay sekunders mellanrum."

foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    #   Skriv ut status på tjänsten i passande färg.
    $getservicestatus4 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename4 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus4 -eq "Stopped") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename4 -ComputerName $server -Status Running
        Write-Host "$server $servicename4 Startad!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server startas..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }

    $getservicestatus3 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename3 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus3 -eq "Stopped") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename3 -ComputerName $server -Status Running
        Write-Host "$server $servicename3 Startad!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server startas..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }

    $getservicestatus2 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename2 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus2 -eq "Stopped") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename2 -ComputerName $server -Status Running
        Write-Host "$server $servicename2 Startad!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server startas..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }

    $getservicestatus1 = (Get-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server).status
    if ($getservicestatus1 -eq "Stopped") {
        Set-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server -Status Running
        Write-Host "$server $servicename1 Startad!" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Väntar i $delay sekunder innan nästa server startas..."
        $nexttime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($delay)
        Write-Host "Nästa start sker $nexttime"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $delay
    }
}

Write-Host "." -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
Read-Host "Tryck ENTER för att avsluta"
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: et-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Orbit Utveckling Integration'.
At E:\stoppstart.ps1:12 char:22
+ ... ervicestatus1 = Get-Service -Name $servicename1 -ComputerName $server
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Orbit Utveckling Integration:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Comment: Does the service exist and have you spelled the name correctly?

Comment: Yes! The service is available but do not know what will be like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure service dependencies so that a service will only start/stop once its dependent services are also started/stopped.

Once you've done this you only need to stop `service1` and Windows will deal with stopping the services dependencies... in order of their dependents.

You can see other services that have dependencies in Services. For example `Fax` service depends on `Print Spooler`, which itself depends on `RPC`, which then depends on `DCOM`

[image]

If manually stopped the `Fax` service, you'll see the GUI stop (in order) DCOM, RPC, Spooler then Fax.

---

Configuring dependencies only needs to be done once (per server):

```
sc config "service1" depend= "service2"
sc config "service2" depend= "service3"
sc config "service3" depend= "service4"
etc...
```

(There's no native Powershell command for doing this to my knowledge, I've only found `sc.exe` and using wmi, with `sc` being the simpler command.)

After this is setup you would only need a small bit of code to restart all the services in order:

```
$serverlist = Get-Content ".\server.txt"
foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    Get-Service -Name "service1" -ComputerName $server | Restart-Service
}
```